# Проблема при перестроении сетки для другого разрешения

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Возникла проблема при перестроении сетки в зависимости от разрешения экрана.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
</div>

<style>
  .wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .item {
    width: 100%;
  }
</style>
```

Таким образом три блока встают друг под другом, растягиваясь на всю ширину и центрируясь. При разрешениях выше определенного значения, сетка выглядит по другому: блок 2 занимает левую половину контейнера, а блоки 1 и 3 находятся друг под другом по правую сторону от блока 1.

```
.item {
  width: 50%;
}

.item:first-of-type {
  order: 2;
{

.item:nth-of-type(2) {
  order: 1;
}

.item-last-of-type {
  order: 3;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

При таком коде всё практически становится на свои места кроме одного: если блок 2 (который слева) выше блока 1 (который сверху справа), то блок 3 (который снизу справа) не становится сразу под блок 1. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как заставить блок 3 не учитывать высоту блока 1 ?
Отрицательный margin-top не подойдет, так как блоки заполняются контентом. Фиксированная высота + overflow: visible/scroll не подходит, так как контент может быть также разной высоты. Сломал голову, пока остановился на варианте с двумя блоками в разметке (во втором блоке разметки объединяю блок 1 и 3 в контйнер), которые переключаются свойством display: none; . Неужели такая типовая задача не может быть решена такими гибкими флексами?

Answer (score 1):

Без дополнительной обертки для двух правых колонок вам не обойтись.
Решение на [codepen](https://codepen.io/kostyabushuev/pen/PoozgyG)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.item {
  padding: 1em;
  min-height: 10px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.item-1 {
  background-color: tomato;
  min-height: 250px;
}

.item-2 {
  background-color: YellowGreen;
}

.item-3 {
  background-color: CornflowerBlue;
}

/***********************/

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.right {
  width: 100%;
}

.item {
  width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  .item-1 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  
  .right {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 50%
  }
  
  .item-3 {
    flex-grow: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item item-1">1</div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="item item-2">2</div>
    <div class="item item-3">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Такой вариант не подходит, так как при меньшем разрешении между блоками 2 и 3 должен стоять блок 1

Comment: В таком случае я могу предложить три варианта:

1. Использовать css-grid
2. Использовать flex, но высоту и положение блока высчитывать на JS (не самый оптимальный вариант)
3. Использовать дублирование (тоже не самый лучший вариант, но более гуманный, чем через JS)